# How to check data in mysql using limit?

Tags: php, mysql

How to check data in mysql using limit ?

When load this code (`will check data in row id 2`) , it's echo `requests field`

Why not echo `not requests field`

this is test_table:

```
________________________________
|  id  |  pro_id  |  requests  |
|  1   |  11111   |     0      |
|  2   |  12345   |     0      |
|  3   |  12345   |     0      |
|  4   |  12345   |     1      |
|__5___|__12345___|_____1______|
```

and this is php code for check data in test_table

```
<?PHP
    include("connect.php");
    $i = "0";

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE pro_id = '12345' AND requests != '0' order by id asc limit $i,1";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    $result = mysql_fetch_array($query);
    if($result)
        echo "requests field";
    else
        echo "not requests field";
?>
```

Comment: no idea what you are asking

Comment: Why is `$i` initialized as a string constant and not integer like `$i=0`?

Comment: because you put it in ""? try $i=(int)0;

Comment: try checking if your query failed -> `$query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());`.

Answer (score 1):

Because $result is result-set it have 0 rows

```
if(array)
    true;
   else
    false;
```

it will always return true. because empty array is never equal FALSE;

Answer (score 1):

Your PHP script will generate a query like this `SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE pro_id = '12345' AND requests != '0' order by id asc limit 0,1`
. And the query output will be like this:

```
+----+---------+----------+
| id | prod_id | requests |
+----+---------+----------+
| 4  | 12345   | 1        |
+----+---------+----------+
```

So, your PHP script :

```
if($result)
    echo "requests field";
else
    echo "not requests field";
```

is always returns `true` value, because your query with your specific condition will found a record, which means `$result` has `true` value.

> FYI: if a query returns an empty record which is `empty array`, it will return
>   a `false` value

I assume that you want to know that, `id=2` record is exist or not while specific condition assigned. So you might modified your PHP script like this:

```
if($result){
   if($result["id"]==2) 
      echo "requests field";
   else
      echo "not requests field";
}
else
    echo "not requests field";
```

Hope it helps.